Android studio HAXM inst
I've encountered an issue with enabling virtualization on my system despite trying various methods. I've already enabled virtualization in the BIOS settings, and I've also enabled Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform features in Windows. However, I'm still unable to run Android Studio, specifically the Hedgehog version, with emulator support. I keep encountering an error related to virtualization.
Here are the steps I've already taken:
Enabled virtualization in the BIOS settings.
Enabled Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform features in Windows.
Despite these efforts, the issue persists. What else can I try to resolve this problem and successfully run Android Studio with emulator support? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

If you have enabled Hyper-V in Windows all other other virtualization techniques like HAXM will no longer work.

According to Configure VM acceleration on Windows HAXM is no longer used if Emulator v33 or higher is used. The necessary steps for acceleration with Hyper-V ware documented here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows-whpx

what error message do you see if you start an emulator?
If you click Tools->SDK Manager, and select SDK Tools check if you installed
Android SDK Build-Tools
Android Emulator
Android SDK Platform-Tools
Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator

ok what is the difference between a comment and an answer?
